# What is the standard procedure to patching a third party package while also being able to merge updates further down?

Tags: git, github, npm, version-control

I only know the very basics of git so I am unsure how to do this or if there is a better/easier way. Suppose a have a third party package from NPM and I need to modify it to add a feature/patch etc but further down the line the contributors of this package release an update. How do I update the package with the newest version or with specific files while also merging the changes that were already there?

Currently I rename the module, download the new package and manually copy/paste the code but this is very error prone and laborious.

Comment: I would urge you to contribute your code back to the original package.

Comment: You marked the question with tags [git] and [github]. Do you mean you use `git` for development? And when you say "download the new package" do you mean you `git clone` the new version or `git pull`? I ask because with git "the standard procedure" is quite simple.

Comment: Well my code is often very specific to my project. @phd    I tagged this with git since I use it for version control but these are npm modules I install through npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the standard procedure with `git` is to update from upstream. Find the source repository for the interested `npm` module, clone it to your local repo, create a separate branch and patch it with your changes. Every time you find the `npm` module's repository was changed you update the master branch in your local repository:

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

and merge the master into your branch:

```
git merge master  # to the current branch
```

Or you can choose rebase instead of merge

```
git rebase master  # rebase the current branch on top of master
```

Verify that your patches are applied properly:

```
git diff master  # compare the branch with master
```

In both merge and rebase scenarios conflicts are possible if the upstream has changed code in the same places where your changes are applied. There is no way around that, you will have to fix these conflicts manually. Anyway it's much less work than copying and patching every time.

If the `npm` module doesn't have a repository accessible to you create one yourself. Create a new `git` repo, get the module's code and commit it to the repo in branch `master`. Create a branch with your patches. Every time you find the upstream code was changed you download the code and update `master`:

```
git checkout master
# Update code
git add -A .
git commit
git checkout your-patched-branched
git merge master  # or rebase
```